# Extract only data (without response element) using MarkLogic search API with REST

Tags: rest, marklogic

When making REST endpoint call to MarkLogic, is there an option to get only the data in the response without the additional metadata?

I am trying to use to make such connections using tools like Tableau, Qlik, Denodo etc

Options I use in the POST body on the URL: http://localhost:8000/v1/search

```
<search xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
<options>
<extract-document-data selected="all"></extract-document-data>
<transform-results apply="raw" />
</options>
</search>
```

Result I get:

```
<search:response snippet-format="raw" total="150" start="1" page-length="10" selected="all" xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <search:result index="1" uri="/doc/21_doc.xml" path="fn:doc(&quot;/doc/21_doc.xml&quot;)" score="0" confidence="0" fitness="0" href="/v1/documents?uri=%2Fdoc%2F21_doc.xml" mimetype="application/xml" format="xml">
        <root>
            <col1>data1</col1>
            <col2>data1</col2>
            <col3>data1</col3>
        </root>
        <search:extracted kind="element">
            <root>
                <col1>data1</col1>
                <col2>data1</col2>
                <col3>data1</col3>
           </root>
        </search:extracted>
    </search:result>
    <search:metrics>
        <search:query-resolution-time>PT0.0005236S</search:query-resolution-time>
        <search:snippet-resolution-time>PT0.0001001S</search:snippet-resolution-time>
        <search:extract-resolution-time>PT0.0003971S</search:extract-resolution-time>
        <search:total-time>PT0.0021503S</search:total-time>
    </search:metrics>
</search:response>
```

Expected:

```
    <search:extracted kind="element">
        <root>
            <col1>data1</col1>
            <col2>data1</col2>
            <col3>data1</col3>
       </root>
    </search:extracted>
```

Also, why am I getting data in both extracted and result elements?

Answer (score 0):

Both snippeting and data extraction provide access to content. Use either, or use them for different purposes. If you only like to get extracted data, then use:

```
<transform-results apply="empty-snippet" />
```

HTH!

Comment: I have used `<transform-results apply="raw" />` in my post body. This does not even return the snippet element which is good for me.
But the requirement is I do not want the response and extract elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the original documents, specify an Accept header of multipart-mixed and specify only the content value for the a category URI parameter.

See: https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/search
and https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/bulk#id_65903

As an alternative, you may find it easier to provide rows to Business Intelligence Tools by creating TDE indexes and paging over an Optic query with the /v1/rows endpoint.

See: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_34628
and https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/rows

Hoping that helps,

Comment: the accept-multipart/mixed does return the data but also returns some header information as given below. Can this be avoided?
 `--ML_BOUNDARY_2249802654100809912
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="/doc/21_doc.xml"; category=content; format=xml
Content-Length: 435`
2. /rows requires me to create TDE templates, correct? Would I rather not use views with ODBC connection to expose data to BI tools.

Comment: The "header" information delimits documents as required by the multipart mime type.  The /v1/rows endpoint can get all of the rows as CSV, line-delimited JSON payloads, or per-page JSON or XML payloads. The BI tool can drive the ODBC connection for you; the /v1/rows endpoint provides an alternative if you need more control.

Comment: I do not want to use /v1/rows as it requires TDE creation. That defeats the whole purpose of using REST over ODBC. If I use REST, I do not need to create any additional documents and indexes inside my database. Correct me if I am wrong.
Secondly, I am unable to remove the boundaries when multipart/mixed is used. If you could help with this section, it would be great.

Comment: Most programming languages have public libraries for parsing a multipart.  In particular, if you're using Java or Node.js, the MarkLogic Java and Node.js Client APIs provide request interfaces that do the work for you.  I know that dotNet also include a multipart parser library, though I'm shallow in dotNet.